# how to add forward proxy to azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, proxy, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service

I have azure app service which runs .net core web api. This api access several external API s to get data and those external services has to whitelist the outbound ip addresses of my app service.

Azure app service has several outbound ip addresses and it can be change when upgrade/downgrade app service or when make internal changes like changing app service plan or resource group.

Is there any solution in azure to setup this app service behind a forward proxy ?, so i can share the IP of the forward proxy to external parties.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to add all App services under a virtual network and create a Virtual Network Gateway to all outbound connections.

This would potentially need below azure services to be created:
- Virtual network
- Subnet
- Virtual Network gateway
- Routing tables (to route traffic via Gateway)

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be sharing a domain name rather than IP address. Here's how to configure it directly in the Azure Portal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

You can also add an API Management in front of your web app and use it as API gateway and also apply policies on it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

Comment: I have domain mapped already, but most of the external systems who whitelist request the IP address for whitelisting.  

I thought of API management is more like reverse proxy. let me search more on this. 
thanks !!

Comment: with API management, for incoming request it will help to hide the app service and act as a extra layer in front. 
But when hosted app service wants to access some external api to get required data that request will not go through API management right ? since it is originated from my app

Comment: my bad, I didn't understand your requirements. You're write, it will be placed in front of the traffic and will not affect the requests your API performs